# Need to put @Index even when I marked with @Column(unique=true)?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Need to put @Index even when I marked with @Column(unique=true) ?

I have a property that will be used frequently to retrieve the entity and wanted to make it an index column on the database. So this property is already marked with @Column(unique=true), do I need to put @Index?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most databases do implement `UNIQUE` constraints using a `UNIQUE INDEX`, but they aren't required to and a `UNIQUE` constraint does not necessarily give you the benefits of an index. In theory, a constraint would not be considered by the query planner whereas an index would be.

That said, in the particular case of MySQL, it seems that [a `UNIQUE` constraint and a `UNIQUE INDEX` are "synonymous"](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,70887,70887#msg-70887).

But you should confirm that by checking the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using mysql as the question is tagged with mysql

If you are using annotations and something like this
@Column(unique = true)

Then this gets converted to the following DDL by hibernate
unique (user_id)

When you query the mysql db and do 
show index from 
It would show user_id as an indexed field, so the answer is @unique is enough for the field to be indexed

HTH